# Math.pow difficulty

Tags: java, pow

When I enter 1000 for investment amount 4.25 for monthly interest rate and 1 for years, why do I get the result 4.384414858452464E11 instead of the expected 1043.34?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinancialApplicationFutureInvestment_13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter investment amount: ");
        int investmentAmount = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter monthly interest rate: ");
        double monthlyInterestRate = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter number of years");
        int numOfYears = input.nextInt();

        double futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount *
            (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, numOfYears * 12));
        System.out.println("Accumulated value is: " + futureInvestmentValue);

        double test = Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, numOfYears * 12);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `1043.34`? I get `1647.83` if I divide the interest rate by 100 as suggested below.

Comment: 4.25% per month is ~64.7% per year. That should produce a large result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monthly interest rate will probably need to be entered as 0.0425

Comment: when use 0.0425 I get 1647.8313602236476

Comment: Is that really the solution? To change the program specification so as to burden the user?

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter That cannot be the correct answer because it's not much more than 4.25% more than the initial investment. After one month you would have $1042.5, and after two months about $40 more.

Comment: for Potatoswatter; I did not change the program spec to burden the user. I just pointed out that the 4.25 needed to be 0.0425 in the calculation. Change the program to divide by 100 and ready.

Answer (score 2):

`1 + monthlyInterestRate`

Is `monthlyInterestRate` a raw factor, or is it expressed in percentage points?

Try dividing by one hundred.

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter It is rhetorical question ;v)

Answer (score 2):

the formula is

```
A = P(1+r/100)^n
```

so it should be

```
investmentAmount * (Math.pow(1 + (monthlyInterestRate/100), numOfYears * 12));
```

Comment: still i get a wrong answer, i get 1647.8313602236476 instead of 1043.34

Comment: i thought it was mountly but the result is yearly

Answer (score 2):

well, you compute 1+4.25 (5.25) as monthly interest rate, instead of 1+(4.25/100) .

Answer (score 1):

you should use casting in System.out.println  (double to int) -- 
(int)(futureInvestmentValue * 100) / 100.0